# How do you return 1 value from an html table?

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to get one piece of data from a table online and the code I have so far is returning all the  linked data preceded by the first <th in the first table. I only want to get back the Detected but not Quantified text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

c = "HMDB0059897"
res = requests.get("https://hmdb.ca/metabolites/" + c)
html_page = res.content
soup = bs(html_page, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table")

headings = [th.get_text().strip() for th in table.find("tr").find_all("th")]

datasets = []
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    datasets = dict(zip(headings, (td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td"))))
    datasets.append(dataset)

print(datasets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to only select the value of "Status" row:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

c = "HMDB0059897"
res = requests.get("https://hmdb.ca/metabolites/" + c)
html_page = res.content
soup = bs(html_page, "html.parser")

status = soup.select_one('th:-soup-contains("Status") + td')
print(status.text)
```

Prints:

```
Detected but not Quantified
```